# JavaScript Get real length of a string (without entities)

Tags: javascript, html-entities

I need to determine the length of string which may contain html-entities.

For example "&darr ;" (↓) would return length 6, which is correct, but I want these entities to be counted as only 1 character.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<div id="foo">&darr;</div>

alert(document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML.length); // alerts 1
```

So based on that rationale, create a div, append your mixed up entity ridden string to it, extract the HTML and check the length.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "&darr;&darr;&darr;&darr;";
alert(div.innerHTML.length); // alerts 4
```

[**Try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/e89hJ/)

You might want to put that in a function for convenience, e.g.:

```
function realLength(str) { // maybe there's a better name?
    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.innerHTML = str;
    return el.innerHTML.length;   
}
```

Comment: I [modified the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e89hJ/1/) and tested this solution against the inputs and outputs on the library-based solution I posted and there was some inconsistency. Namely, I entered an encoded input and got 110 chars, then entered a decoded input of the same data and got 96 chars. Not sure why exactly, but it might be worth checking on.

Comment: @Nathan Taylor - The inconsistency could feasibly be caused by jQuery's `.val`, or line breaks.

Comment: @Nathan - Second update using the DOM .value property, seems to work just fine, provided you don't hit enter anywhere in the textarea (each \n == 1 char): http://jsfiddle.net/e89hJ/2/

Answer (score 3):

Since there's no solution using jQuery yet:

```
var str = 'lol&amp;';
alert($('<span />').html(str).text().length); // alerts 4
```

Uses the same approach like karim79, but it never adds the created element to the document.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but karim's answer does not add the element to the document either.

Comment: Hrm ok, looks like I had only read half of his answer (or he edited it)

Answer (score 3):

You could for most purposes assume that an ampersand followed by letters, or a possible '#' and numbers, followed by a semicolon, is one character.

```
var strlen=string.replace(/&#?[a-zA-Z0-9]+;/g,' ').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the javascript in a browser I would suggest using it to help you. You can create an element and set its innerHTML to be your string containing HTML-entities. Then extract the contents of that element you just created as text.

Here is an example (uses Mootools): http://jsfiddle.net/mqchen/H73EV/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, JavaScript does not natively support encoding or decoding of HTML entities, which is what you will need to do to get the 'real' string length. I was able to find this third-party library which is able to decode and encode HTML entities and it appears to work well enough, but there's no guaranteeing how *complete* it will be.

http://www.strictly-software.com/htmlencode

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 (introduces `codePointAt()`:

```
function strlen (str) {
    let sl = str.length
    let chars = sl
    for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) if (str.codePointAt(i) > 65535) {
       chars--;
       i++;
    }
    return chars
}
```

Beware `charCodeAt()` does not work the same way.