# Calculate real length of a string, like we do with the caret

Tags: javascript, string-length

What I want is to calculate how much time the caret will move from the beginning till the end of the string.

**Explanations:**
Look this string `""` in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RFuQ3/
If you put the caret before the first quote then push the right arrow <kbd>►</kbd> you will push 3 times to arrive after the second quote (instead of 2 times for an empty string).

The first way, and the easiest to calculate the length of a string is `<string>.length`.
But here, it returns 2.

The second way, from [JavaScript Get real length of a string (without entities)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788242/javascript-get-real-length-of-a-string-without-entities) gives 2 too.

How can I get 1?

---

<sup>1-I thought to a way to put the string in a text input, and then do a `while` loop with a `try{setCaret}catch(){}`

2-It's just for fun</sup>

Comment: Just add one to the length returned?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? That would probably be useful to know. Are you wanting to track cursor crawling left-to-right to detect or manipulate something?

Comment: Also, can you demonstrate that effect somewhere other than jsFiddle, which is something of a unique editing environment? In other words, regular `input` and `textarea` don't have this effect. jsFiddle's text manipulation scripts aren't perfectly tuned.

Comment: @JaredFarrish If a user push the arrow to count the length in a textbox, he will get `x`. In most cases ("foo",123,ಠ_ಠ) `length` will give x. But not in my example.

Comment: See my second comment. Do you have another place to demonstrate that's not jsFiddle? What kind of "cursor-based" environment do have to work with?

Comment: @JaredFarrish You are right, in jsbin the length is 2 !!! But in TextEdit (on Mac) it's 1. Ahhh! How can we know?

Comment: What environments are you needing to design code for? In a browser window? In a `textarea` or a `contenteditable="true"` element? That makes a difference.

Comment: The content will be in a variable. (When I was talking about textbox, it was to, maybe, use the idea I said at the bottom of my question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character in your question "󠀁" is the 
[Unicode Character 'LANGUAGE TAG' (U+E0001)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e0001).

From the following Stack Overflow questions,

- " [Expressing UTF-16 unicode characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126384)"
- " [How can I tell if a string contains multibyte characters in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877326)"

we learn that

> [JavaScript strings are UCS-2 encoded](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding) but can represent Unicode code points outside the Basic Multilingual Pane (`U+0000`-`U+D7FF` and `U+E000`-`U+FFFF`) using two 16 bit numbers (a UTF-16 surrogate pair), the first of which must be in the range `U+D800`-`U+DFFF`.

The [UTF-16 surrogate pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Surrogates) representing "󠀁" is `U+DB40` and `U+DC01`. In decimal `U+DB40` is 56128, and `U+DC01` is 56321.

```
console.log("".length); // 2
console.log("".charCodeAt(0)); // 56128
console.log("".charCodeAt(1)); // 56321
console.log("\uDB40\uDC01" === ""); // true
console.log(String.fromCharCode(0xDB40, 0xDC01) === ""); // true
```

Adapting the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4885062/788324, we just need to count the number of code points to arrive at the correct answer:

```
var getNumCodePoints = function(str) {
    var numCodePoints = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);
        if ((charCode & 0xF800) == 0xD800) {
            i++;
        }
        numCodePoints++;
    }
    return numCodePoints;
};

console.log(getNumCodePoints("")); // 1
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RFuQ3/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
function realLength(str) {
    var i = 1;
    while (str.substring(i,i+1) != "") i++;
    return (i-1);
}
```

Didn't try the code, but it should work I think.

Comment: Accepting the premise of the ghost hault on the cursor, [`"2"`](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/RFuQ3/2/) still has the issue after the first `"` (in Firefox).

Comment: @user1493235 Sorry, but it doen't work, it just return `<string>.length-1` Look this http://jsfiddle.net/zDwPu/ (And test the real length with your caret)

Comment: This solution is slow (`.substring(i,i+1)` instead of `[i]`), wrong (`var i = 1;`) and useless (isn't the answer to the question).

Comment: No down votes for "Didn't try the code, but it should work I think." ?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't really support unicode.
You can try

```
yourstring.replace(/[\uD800-\uDFFF]{2}/g, "0").length
```

for what it's worth

Comment: Are you sure that uDFFF is the limit?

Comment: I did not understand very well. The limit is `\uFFFF` or `\uDFFF`? What should I use? And why? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? It's written `uDFFF`, what other limit could be there? Probably, more correct expression would be `yourstring.replace(/[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]/g, "0").length`, but who cares, really...

Comment: panda-34, did somebody step on your birthday cake today? Lil' pessimism much?